# checkbox Default Value "Checked" giving undefined value using jquery 1.9.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova-3

here is the jquery code :

```
    var htmlCopyDialog = "";
   if ($("#main7 option:selected").text() != "Service Only") {
```

i am setting checkbox as checked by default after checking condition and calling function:

```
if(maintainCopyCheckbox)
        {  

      htmlCopyDialog += '<input type="checkbox" name="isService" id="isService" checked ="checked" data-theme="d"/>';
     htmlCopyDialog += '<label for="isService" >This is to be a service quote</label>';
      showCallNumber(maintainCopyCheckbox);
      }
      else
        {
    htmlCopyDialog += '<input type="checkbox" onclick="showCallNumber(maintainCopyCheckbox);" name="isService" id="isService" data-theme="d"/>';
      htmlCopyDialog += '<label for="isService" >This is to be a service quote</label>';
           }

    }
     htmlCopyDialog += '</div>';
```

**in function:**

```
var setFlagForCheckbox = 0;

function showCallNumber(maintainCopyCheckbox1) {
    console.log("showCallNumber method call" + maintainCopyCheckbox1);
    if (maintainCopyCheckbox1) {
        console.log("if first condition" + $('#isService').defaultChecked);
        if ($("#isService").defaultChecked) {

            console.log("inside if condition" + maintainCopyCheckbox1);
        }
    }
}
```

here is the Log:

> 11-03 18:05:09.820: I/Web Console(8324): if first conditionundefined
>   at file:///android_asset/www/js/survey/infoqueries.js:1062

can someone help me why its giving me undefined ....
     console.log("if first condition" + $('#isService').defaultChecked); 
    i also have tried **.is(:checked)**   and .prop   both are giving me undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$("#isService")` returns a jQuery object which does not have the `defaultChecked` property, it is a property of the dom element. So you need to access the dom element reference, in this case `$("#isService")[0]` gives you the dom element with id `isService`.

```
console.log("if first condition" + $("#isService")[0].defaultChecked);
if ($("#isService")[0].defaultChecked) {
```

UPDATE:
Looks like there is a much basic problem because the `showCallNumber` method is invoked before the underlying html elements area added to the dom, so `$("#isService")` will not return any elements. You need to call the method `showCallNumber` only after the the html structure is added to the dom structure

Comment: ITS GIVING ME ERROR CANT READ PROPERTY defaultChecked  FOR UNDEFINED